# gitlab ci job with artifacts report and path

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So, what I want to be able to do is something like that:

```
rspec:
  script:
    - gem install rspec_junit_formatter
    - bundle exec rspec spec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out rspec.xml
  artifacts:
    name: "rspec"
    reports:
        junit: rspec.xml
    name: "coverage"
    paths:
        - coverage/
```

that is getting out of the ran spec the spec report and the coverage folder(which is then zipped and yada yada yada). I wouldn't mind also getting another version of the spec.... (but that it can easily be done by adding another outputter to the rspec command and add the path to the paths key, am I right?)

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but if anybody finds this because there are no artifacts, this helped me: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html#viewing-junit-screenshots-on-gitlab Artifacts are not uploaded if a job fails, by default, so you have to set when: always.

Comment: @T_01 Indeed you need to add `when: always` in your artifacts section.